I live in an an older apartment complex, and the walls are painted every time a tenant moves out. Could this make it hard to find a stud?
I live in an older apartment complex. The walls are painted every time a tenant moves out of the apartment. Could it be that the multiple layers of paint are making it difficult for me to find a stud using a stud finder?

It might depend more on how the walls are made.   Old apartment might be concrete or plaster walls instead of wood studs and drywall.  Talk to the landlord/maintenance people.

If you are using one of the cheap magnetic stud finders, multiple layers of paint can definitely affect its accuracy. @Cheery has a great post on how to find studs that has worked for me many times.

It's possible, but unlikely. A stud finder works by measuring differences in the density of materials.
But you can always use the traditional stud finder: take a coat hanger and make a 90-deg bend at 9 inches. Make a small hole in the wall and insert the 9-in section so that it is parallel to the wall. Then turn it until it hits a stud. Once you find the first stud, the others are at 16" intervals on-center.
